# Typescript: Identifier 'X' is not defined. 'Y' does not contain such a member

Tags: angular, typescript

My program still runs but I'm getting the error message so I want to fix this in case it causes a break somewhere else.

I have created an interface which looks like this...

```
export interface IAudit {
    retentionDays: number;
    server: string;
    selection: ISelection[];
}

export interface ISelection {
    name: string;
    displayName: string;
    events: IEvent;
}

export interface IEvent {
    [name: string]: {
        available: boolean;
        enable: boolean;
    };
}
```

example this will look like

```
'addition': { available: true, enable: false },
'deletion': { available: true, enable: false }
```

I am using it here:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of model.selection">
<div class="col-xs-2 no-pl no-pr text-center">
{{ item.events.addition.available ?item.events.addition.enable : 'N/A' }}</div>

<div class="col-xs-2 no-pl no-pr text-center">
{{ item.events.deletion.available ? item.events.deletion.enable : 'N/A' }}</div>
</div>
```

model.selection is ISelection[]

addition and deletion is being flagged as not existing in the interface.

Identifier 'addition' is not defined. 'Y' does not contain such a member

Is name correct or should I be approaching this from a different angle?

Comment: What is the type for `item`?

Comment: export interface IAudit {
    retentionDays: number;
    server: string;
    selection: ISelection[];
}

export interface ISelection {
    name: string;
    displayName: string;
    events: IEvent;
}

export interface IEvent {
    [name: string]: {
        available: boolean;
        enable: boolean;
    };
}

Item is ISelection in this case... I'll add above